# How to conditionally skip sending e-mail verification in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I've configured my server with `sendVerificationEmail: true` which is what I want in the general case. However, there are cases, where I don't want Meteor to send out a verification e-mail. Instead, I would like to flag the e-mail as verified programmatically.

I've tried to do it in the validateNewUser hook

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function(user) {
  user.emails[0].verified = true;
  return true;
});
```

and in the onCreateUser hook

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  user.emails[0].verified = true;
  return user;
});
```

both without success. Although the email gets flagged as verified, Meteor still sends out a verification e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the automatic email verification via `sendVerificationEmail: false` and do it manually in the situations you would like to verify the email

```
var email = user.emails[0].address;
Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId, email);
```

Comment: The problem with this is I don't know when to call `sendVerificationEmail`. I can't do it in the `onCreateUser` callback as the user doesn't exist there yet (i. e. I get a "Error: Can't find user").

Comment: You could do it shortly after `onCreateUser` is called using a `Meteor.setTimeout(function() {sendVerification...}, 10000);` inside `onCreateUser`